# Send response to client in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Unable to send response data back to client. Its throwing error saying `response.write()` is not a function:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.set('port', (port));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('/');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

app.post('/login', verifyLogin);

function verifyLogin(req, res, next) {
    var loginParams = {
        'username': req.body.username,
        'password': req.body.password
    };

    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8084/xxx/auth', //URL to hit
        qs: {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password
        }
        }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
        response.write(body); // ERROR here response.write is not a function
        return response;
    }
});
```

I am getting the response data in command prompt console but how do I send response data back to client?

Comment: use response.send() or res.send() function instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing your `response.write` with `res.write`?

You're using the `response` from the `request` callback, and not the `res` from the `app.post` callback

Answer (score 6):

`res.send()` is used to send response to the client.

```
function verifyLogin(req, res, next) {
    var loginParams = {
        'username': req.body.username,
        'password': req.body.password
    };

    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8084/xxx/auth', //URL to hit
        qs: {username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password
        }
        }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
        //response.write(body); // ERROR here response.write is not a function

          res.send(body);// AND IT SHOULD BE USUALLY TRUE OR WITH THE OBJECT
//SO IT CAN ALSO BE 
             res.send(true);
//            return response;
        }
    });
```

For instance, It is written as

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Here is the reference http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Why does nobody actually show an example of receiving a web request, making another HTTP request, and then returning data to the client? Why is that not listed anywhere I can find? It is the very most common case and I can't find it anywhere.